# Google analytics. Different platforms of same app. Same tracking code or different?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase, mobile-analytics

I have the same app in different platforms (MyApp for Android and MyApp for iOS). Google suggests using **different** properties in this case. [HERE](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en) is the link to google's suggestion.

But I would like to go against google's recommendation and use the **same** tracking property. Using the same tracking property,  I can view data from multiple platforms together in one place. If I want to view data for one platform, I can create multiple views and view separated data as well.

As I am going against google's recommended approach, I am worried a little. Did anyone do this before? Are there any problems I will face using this setup. Can someone give more information on why google recommends this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This will not cause issues as all URL's are different in the platforms, yes it is easier to manage data when they are separated in different properties. But this is not a requirement, it just requires you to do a lot more effort to create views to filter out the data you do not want in there.

With the events/other data, make sure that you are able to keep them apart with filtering. If you can't filter them out, something is wrong with your setup!

But in this regard you need to follow Google's advice to keep one master view with all data unfiltered so if you do something wrong, you will not lose any analytics data.

Another approach you can also use is to use one "master property" that is installed on all platforms, and each platform with its separate tracking next to it. Once you feel comfortable with the "master property" and the data that it is collecting, just disable the platform specific one.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using same tracking id for both platforms. It's easy to see difference between platforms. Example from within the behaviour flow:

[image: Google Analytics Behaviour Flow]

Comment: @stevieb if you mouseover the link, you'll see it's an image, right?

Comment: @stevieb I tried to include the image as a part of the answer, but just selected the upload image button, when creating post, and the image appeared as a link. Anyways, hope this answer turns out useful, at least it is what I needed when trying to answer the original question my self.